# Spring Session not working on Tomcat 8 when using Tiles - SESSION Cookie is not set as response is already included

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8, spring-session

I am using Spring Session 1.2.0.RELEASE on a Spring Boot Project. This is packaged as a war and deployed on Tomcat 8.

I have followed Spring Session documentation and configured it properly. The problem is that the entry point to the application is a controller that sets some value on session but the SESSION cookie is not sent to the browser.

Debugging I see that:

1. `org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy.onNewSession()` tries to write the cookie:

   `this.cookieSerializer
                   .writeCookieValue(new CookieValue(request, response, cookieValue));`
2. `org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer.writeCookieValue()` sets the cookie in the response:

   `response.addCookie(sessionCookie);`
3. The cookie isn't actually written. The underlying response object is `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpResponse`. Its `addCookie()` method is:

   ```
   /**
     *  Disallow <code>addCookie()</code> calls on an included response.         
     *  @param cookie The new cookie
     */
   @Override
   public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {

       if (!included)
           ((HttpServletResponse) getResponse()).addCookie(cookie);

   }
   ```

The problem is that `included` attribute, which at some point is set true, preventing the cookie from being added.

This happens when the jsp (using tiles) is being serviced:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

This is the moment when the response is being marked as included (when standard.jsp tiles layout is inserting an attribute:

`<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" ignore="false"/>`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around this problem I ended up creating a filter to enforce the creation of the session.

As seen, the first call to the controller didn't add the cookie because during the Tiles-JSP rendering the response was already marked as included. What I do is forcing the creation of the session in the filter and redirecting asking the very same requestURI. This way, since the call doesn't involve a tiles rendering the cookie is created and can be used right away in the next calls.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("${sessionEnforcerFilter.enabled:true}")
public FilterRegistrationBean sessionEnforcerFilter(){
    logger.info("Registering sessionEnforcerFilter");
    FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    frb.setName("sessionEnforcerFilter");
    frb.setFilter(new SessionEnforcerFilter());
    frb.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"/*"}));
    return frb;
}

public class SessionEnforcerFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        if(httpServletRequest.getSession(false)==null){
            logger.debug("sessionEnforcerFilter.doFilter () - Session is null - forcing its creation");
            httpServletRequest.getSession();
            String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
            logger.debug("sessionEnforcerFilter.doFilter () - Repeating request [{}]", requestURI);
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(requestURI);
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**summary**

1. Hold breakPoint in SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper.onResponseCommitted().
2. Check that the response object inside the SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper is a non-wrapped response. (included = false)
3. If it is a wrapped response object, make sure that the sessionRepositoryFilter comes first.

================

Spring-session is already handling the problem when 'DispatcherType.INCLUDE (included = true)'.

SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper.onResponseCommitted() is trying to addCookie to the original response object.

The sessionRepositoryFilter must be in the first position to wrap the original applicationHttpResponse passed by tomcat.

**Problem Situation**

- The SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper receives the wrapped response and holds it.
- When executing doInclude() in the servlet container, find the original reponse and wrap it with ApplicationHttpResponse (included = true).
  Then, SetResponse (new wrapping response) to the innermost wrapper.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.24/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher.java#ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.ServletResponse%29

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.24/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher.java#ApplicationDispatcher.wrapResponse%28org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.State%29

- Spring-session does an addCookie on the response (expecting the original response) stored in SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper.onResponseCommitted(), but it can not because it is set to 'included = true'.